# Importing from folders with the same name gives ImportError in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Given the following project structure:

```
test/
 data/
   __init__.py
 a/
   data/
     __init__.py
   main.py
 __init__.py
```

In `test/data/__init__.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
DATA_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
```

In `main.py`

```
from data import DATA_DIR

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(DATA_DIR)
```

When running from the terminal, it works fine. When running from PyCharm, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/<USER>/code/test/a/main.py", line 1, in <module>
from data import DATA_DIR
ImportError: cannot import name 'DATA_DIR' from 'data' 
(/Users/<USER>/code/test/a/data/__init__.py)
```

Has anyone found a way to get around this?

Comment: In your own words, **how do you intend for Python to decide** which `data` is referred to, in the `from data import DATA_DIR` line? Different approaches will make sense depending on what logic you want it to use.

Comment: Also: **what is the current working directory** when you run the code from the terminal? What is it when the code runs from PyCharm? Do you know how to check?

Comment: The current working directory is `test`. Therefore, I intend for Python to pick the outmost `data` dir when doing an import from it. Otherwise, it is impossible to reach. This works as expected when running from the terminal but not in Pycharm.

Comment: If it works from the terminal but not in Pycharm, that is because when it runs from Pycharm, the current working directory is different. Check the project settings.

Comment: If you run the code with `python -m test.a.main` or  `python -m a.main` it works in the terminal. In Pycharm, the current working directory is `test`.

Comment: The working directory should be one level outside that to resolve the issue, if I'm thinking straight. Another way is to ensure the project is installed first, e.g. in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

In PyCharms `Choose target to run` configuration, change from `Script path` to `Module name` and it should work as expected.

Answer (score -2):

`test` isn't in the installed modules. It needs to be a location that [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) knows about.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html#sys-path-init might give you the information you need to add `test` to your `sys.path`.

After you add `test` to the installed modules you might also have to remove `test/a` since otherwise `from data import ...` will have a conflict between the two locations. Both of them have the same name and with both directories accessible only the first one in the list will be seen. The order of the values in `sys.path` matters.